# How to control the row/column-wise printing of plots when using apply functions

Tags: r, iteration, apply, lapply

Consider the following data frame:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:200),
  var1 = rnorm(200),
  var2 = rnorm(200),
  var3 = rnorm(200),
  var4 = rnorm(200)
)
```

We want to use the `lapply()` function to apply `ggqqplot` function from the `ggpubr` package to columns 2:4 of `dat`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
vars <- paste0(names(dat[,2:5]))
lapply(vars, FUN=ggqqplot, data=dat)
```

This works fine, but we want to print the figures side by side (e.g., in 2 rows, 2 columns). How can we do this using the apply framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggqqplot` allows facets using argument `facet_by` (check `?ggqqplot`), so all you have to do is convert your data into facet friendly long form data. see below

```
dat_melt <- reshape2::melt(dat, measure.vars = vars) # converts data into long-form
ggqqplot(dat_melt, x="value", facet.by = "variable")
```

**Edit:**

If you still want to use `apply` functions, the following is the easiest solution I can think of

```
plist <- lapply(vars, FUN = function (x) ggqqplot(dat,x = x))
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plist, ncol = 2)
```

or the pipe-friendly equivalent

```
lapply(vars, FUN = function (x) ggqqplot(dat,x = x)) %>%
  {cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist=.,ncol = 2)}
```

Comment: This solves the problem, to add a similar solution in a `tidyverse` framework, I would add `dat%>%pivot_longer(-c(1), names_to='var', values_to='val')%>%ggqqplot(., x='val', facet.by='var')`. Nevertheless, this question was intended to relate to the `apply` family of functions, so I will see if someone provides a solution in that framework